# Continuous functions with `quickly' divergent second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for functions $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ that are continuous, but with a second derivative that 'quickly' diverges to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to 0$ (or as $x\to 1$). I had $x^{-x}$ or $x^x$ in mind, but their first derivatives diverge approximately like $\ln(x)$ and $1/x$ as $x\to 0$, which is rather slow. What would be an example that diverges faster? For example high degree polynomial rate or even exponential. And are there examples with continuous first derivative perhaps?

Are there any examples with 'nice' formulas? I aim to use it in simulation, so being able to program it would be handy.

Comment: I suggest $$f(x)= \int_x^1 e^{1/t} dt$$ then you have $$f'(x)=\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}$$ and the second derivative is $$f''(x)=\frac{e^{1/x}(1-2x)}{x^4}$$ which grows pretty fast. However these functions are very bad at being approximmated.

Comment: @Crostul this diverges as $x\to 0$ right? Could we somehow modify this to obtain a function continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Nope, the improper integral is actually convergent.